# How to correctly structure pydantic models?

Tags: python, pydantic

I am trying to structure the code for my data model using `pydantic` but I am running into an apparently insolvable problem.

The code below works as expected:

> main.py

```py
#
from __future__ import annotations
#
from pydantic import BaseModel
#
class Item(BaseModel):
    tag: Tag = None
    class Config:
        orm_mode = True

class Tag(BaseModel):
    item: Item = None
    class Config:
        orm_mode = True


Item.update_forward_refs()
Tag.update_forward_refs()

i = Item()
t = Tag()

i.tag = t
t.item = i
# print(i) fails due to cyclic model but this is another story
```

Then I am trying to refactor my code like this:

```sh
main.py
model/item.py
model/tag.py
```

with

> main.py:

```py
#
from model.item import Item
from model.tag import Tag
#
Item.update_forward_refs()
Tag.update_forward_refs()
#
i = Item()
t = Tag()
#
i.tag = t
t.item = i
```

> model/item.py:

```py
#
from __future__ import annotations
#
from pydantic import BaseModel
#
from .tag import Tag
#
class Item(BaseModel):
    tag: Tag = None
    class Config:
        orm_mode = True
```

> model/tag.py:

```py
#
from __future__ import annotations
#
from pydantic import BaseModel
#
from .item import Item
#
class Tag(BaseModel):
    item: Item = None
    class Config:
        orm_mode = True
```

This code fails on import because of the cross reference of tag to item and vice versa.
But if I remove the imports from the model files:

```py
    from .item import Item

    from .tag import Tag
```

The code fails again complaining about missing Tag or Item:

```py
NameError: name 'Tag' is not defined 
NameError: name 'Item' is not defined
```

All other attempts failed, like using explicit reference `model.Item` instead of `Item`.

What is the correct way to get around this, preferably keeping the nice symmetry of the code ?

Comment: Why would you need such a cross dependency in the first place? It's dead wrong to have such a cross reference in a database. Are you sure the relationship isn't Item<-Tag?

Comment: Well, cross dependency is a very natural thing in data modelling and very handy as well. There is no intrinsic problem to code that with any modern ORM either... I do not think this is 'dead wrong' although it indeed requires additional efforts to maintain integrity in a DB.

Comment: I can only judge what I can see and I would find another way of modelling it. Anyway, the straight solution is to put both classes together in the same file. Otherwise, you could specify a dictionary instead of tag/item and validate it by importing the tag/item class and creating an instance of it